# Get type of the returned data in MySQL query

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I know how to get the type of the columns in a standard table (e.g. `SHOW FIELDS FROM ...`), but is there any way to get the types of the returned data from a custom query with various column selections and joins of different tables (e.g. `SELECT table1.var1,table2.var2 FROM table1 JOIN table2`)?

Comment: Well, when you know what datatype a column is (with your `SHOW FIELDS FROM...`) you know what will **always** be in there. It's not gonna change. For example, when you have a `varchar` column but there are numbers in it, the numbers are treated as text, not as numbers. You will notice that, when you try to order by that column.

Comment: After reading a bit, I guess this will do it:

CREATE TABLE temp ENGINE=HEAP SELECT table1.var1,table2.var2 FROM table1 JOIN table2;
SHOW FIELDS FROM temp;

Any better suggestions?

Comment: This will show the same result as `SHOW FIELDS FROM table1; SHOW FIELDS FROM table2;` Actually I wonder why you want to do that.

Comment: Pro tip: google for "mysql information_schema". You'll find a solution which is more dynamic than `SHOW FIELDS...`

Comment: This particular query is just a simple example. Well, the reason is for automatically detecting which sql::ResultSet->getXxx I should use when I extract the data from the result set with the MySQL c++ connector. getInt(int column#) or getDouble(int column#) or ... etc

Answer (score 8):

The article on the MySQL site titled [Developing Database Applications Using MySQL Connector/C++](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html) contains [the following subsection](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html#rsmeta):

> ### Accessing Result Set Metadata
>
> When the SQL statement being processed is unknown until runtime, the `ResultSetMetaData` interface can be used to determine the methods to be used to retrieve the data from the result set. `ResultSetMetaData` provides information about the structure of a given result set. Data provided by the `ResultSetMetaData` object includes the number of columns in the result set, the names or labels and the types of those columns along with the attributes of each column and the names of the table, schema and the catalog the designated column's table belongs to.
>
> When `getMetaData()` is called on a `ResultSet` object, it returns a `ResultSetMetaData` object describing the columns of that `ResultSet` object.
>
> Signatures of some of the relevant methods are shown below. For the complete list of methods supported by `ResultSetMetaData` interface, check the resultset_metadata.h header in your Connector/C++ installation.
>
> ```
> /* resultset.h */
> ResultSetMetaData * ResultSet::getMetaData() const;
>
> /* prepared_statement.h */
> ResultSetMetaData * PreparedStatement::getMetaData() const;
>
> /* resultset_metadata.h */
> std::string ResultSetMetaData::getCatalogName(unsigned int columnIndex);
> std::string ResultSetMetaData::getSchemaName(unsigned int columnIndex);
> std::string ResultSetMetaData::getTableName(unsigned int columnIndex);
>
> unsigned int ResultSetMetaData::getColumnCount();
> unsigned int ResultSetMetaData::getColumnDisplaySize(unsigned int columnIndex);
> std::string ResultSetMetaData::getColumnLabel(unsigned int columnIndex);
> std::string ResultSetMetaData::getColumnName(unsigned int columnIndex);
> int ResultSetMetaData::getColumnType(unsigned int columnIndex);
> std::string ResultSetMetaData::getColumnTypeName(unsigned int columnIndex);
>
> int ResultSetMetaData::isNullable(unsigned int columnIndex);
> bool ResultSetMetaData::isReadOnly(unsigned int columnIndex);
> bool ResultSetMetaData::isWritable(unsigned int columnIndex);
> ```
>
> The following code fragment demonstrates how to retrieve all the column names or labels, their data types and the sizes along with the table name and the schema names to which they belong.
>
> ```
> ResultSet *rs;
> ResultSetMetaData *res_meta;
>
> res_meta = rs -> getMetaData();
>
> int numcols = res_meta -> getColumnCount();
> cout << "\nNumber of columns in the result set = " << numcols << endl;
>
> cout.width(20);
> cout << "Column Name/Label";
>
> cout.width(20);
> cout << "Column Type";
>
> cout.width(20);
> cout << "Column Size" << endl;
>
> for (int i = 0; i < numcols; ++i) {
>   cout.width(20);
>   cout << res_meta -> getColumnLabel (i+1);
>
>   cout.width(20); 
>   cout << res_meta -> getColumnTypeName (i+1);
>
>   cout.width(20); 
>   cout << res_meta -> getColumnDisplaySize (i+1) << endl;
> }
>
> cout << "\nColumn \"" << res_meta -> getColumnLabel(1);
> cout << "\" belongs to the Table: \"" << res_meta -> getTableName(1);
> cout << "\" which belongs to the Schema: \"" << res_meta -> getSchemaName(1) << "\"" << endl;
>
> //delete res_meta;
> delete rs;
> ```
>
> From release 1.0.5 onwards, the connector takes care of cleaning the `ResultSetMetaData` objects automatically when they go out of scope. This will relieve the clients from deleting the `ResultSetMetaData` objects explicitly. Due to the implicit destruction of the metadata objects, clients won't be able to delete the `ResultSetMetaData` objects directly. Any attempt to delete the `ResultSetMetaData` object results in compile time error. Similarly using `auto_ptr` template class to instantiate an object of type `ResultSetMetaData` results in compile time error. For example, compilation of the above code fails with Connector/C++ 1.0.5 and later versions, when the statement `delete res_meta;` is uncommented.
>
> #### Prepared Statements and the Result Set Metadata
>
> `PreparedStatement::getMetaData()` retrieves a `ResultSetMetaData` object that contains information about the columns of the `ResultSet` object, which will be returned when the `PreparedStatement` object is executed.
>
> Because a `PreparedStatement` object is precompiled, it is possible to know about the `ResultSet` object that it will return without having to execute it. Consequently, it is possible to invoke the method `getMetaData` on a `PreparedStatement` object rather than waiting to execute it and then invoking the `ResultSet::getMetaData` method on the `ResultSet` object that is returned.
>
> The method `PreparedStatement::getMetaData` is supported only in Connector/C++ 1.0.4 and later versions.