# Get the resultset field type in mySQL C interface

Tags: mysql, c, recordset

ALL,

I skimmed thru the mySQL C API documentation, but couldn't find it.

Then I googled and I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700751/get-type-of-the-returned-data-in-mysql-query) which is for C++ and not C.

So, the question is - is there a C equivalent for the link above? Or some other means to retrieve the field type of the arbitrary query?

TIA!!

Comment: [Chapter 27 C API Optional Result Set Metadata](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-optional-metadata.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get the field type, you can access the field information after fetching a row  by using mysql_fetch_field() as suggested by Barmar in his comment.

The structure MYSQL_FIELD has a member named `type` which is an enum. The enum enum_field_types can be found in field_types.h.

A complete, self-contained example program might look like this:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void error(MYSQL *con, const char *msg, const char *error) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, error);
    if (con) {
        mysql_close(con);
    }
    exit(1);
}

char *type_info(enum enum_field_types type) {
    switch (type) {
        case MYSQL_TYPE_VARCHAR:
            return "VARCHAR";
        case MYSQL_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL:
            return "NEWDECIMAL";
        case MYSQL_TYPE_LONG:
            return "LONG";
        case MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING:
            return "VAR_STRING";
            //...several cases omitted see field_types.h
        default:
            return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}

int main(void) {
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (con == NULL) {
        error(con, "initialization failed", mysql_error(con));
    }

    if (!mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "admin123", "db", 3306, NULL, 0)) {
        error(con, "couldn't connect", mysql_error(con));
    }

    if (mysql_query(con, "select * from animals;")) {
        error(con, "query failed", mysql_error(con));
    }

    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_use_result(con);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("empty result\n");
    }

    if (mysql_fetch_row(result)) {
        MYSQL_FIELD *field;
        while ((field = mysql_fetch_field(result))) {
            printf("|%s ", field->name);
            printf("%s| ", type_info(field->type));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    mysql_close(con);
    return 0;
}
```

**Test**

For the simple test table Animals, the output of name and type would look like this:

```
|id LONG| |kind VAR_STRING| |name VAR_STRING| |weight NEWDECIMAL|
```